# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.edson.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file

Tags: instantiation

My project does not present any errors in the sync gradles, but when I run the app, there is a crash and the following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.edson, PID: 10843
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.edson.MyApplication package com.example.edson: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.edson.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList.
> And also says:
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.edson.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList

However, MyApplication is properly located in the package of the project and it has the following content:

```
package com.example.edson
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()
```

Also, AndroidManifest.xml is properly written:

```
application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Also, when I run `./gradlew assembleDebug`, there is no errors at all as well.

So, I do not know what is happening. I really appreciate any help and I can share more data as required.

this issue happened when I tried to refactor to viewmodel style and also implement database room (many functions with no use still).